# Proof that relation " is divisor of " is transitive

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and let $R \subseteq A \times A$ be the relation "is a divisor of". How can I prove with algebra that $R$ is transitive?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what "R C A x A" means, but here's the idea.

You want to show that $a|b$ and $b|c$ implies that $a|c$. Well, you know that $c$ is a multiple of $b$, and $b$ is a multiple of $a$, so $c$ must be a multiple of a multiple of $a$. You should just write that out with symbols.

Comment: with the C i meant "is a subset of", i don't really know yet how to use the mathjax. thanks for your help